# How to use Python list comprehensions for sqlite table loading?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm a rookie at SQLite stuff, and a relative noob in Python. I'm collecting process instrument data for a demonstration application. I've written this code:

```
from DAQ_Util import *
from sqlite3 import *


print 'Setting up memory-resident SQL database...'
BenchDB = connect(':memory:')
DBTableSetup = BenchDB.cursor()
DBTableSetup.execute("create table ss2000 (timestamp, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7,  var8, var9)")
DBTableSetup.close()

# Access data from SS2000 TDL Sensor
instReading = ss2000serialRead('192.168.1.121', 4001, 57)
print instReading
SS2000TabPopulate = BenchDB.cursor()
SS2000TabPopulate.execute("insert into ss2000 values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
[instReading(i) for i in instReading])

print '...Done'
```

The DAQ_Util module is a collection of routines for grabbing process data from instruments. `ss2000serialRead` is from DAQ_Util and brings in a list of data strings from such an instrument. Some data is reproduced below. All I'm trying to do is write this data to an `sqlite` table using a list comprehension. It's not working, and I don't know how to interpret the error msg, though I think folks who know more about Python then me may spot the error immediately, or so I hope... :o) A dump of the screen output follows:

```
$ python SQLite-test.py
Setting up memory-resident SQL database...
  Try connecting to serial server...
['2012-08-05 16:52:49.548095', '20.0000', '0.0000', '13.5', '76.60', '8190', '1640', '240', '-13', '79.40']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQLite-test.py", line 17, in <module>
[instReading(i) for i in instReading])
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable 
$
```

Can someone please point out the error?
Thanks!

Thanks Ignacio, here's corrected code:

```
# Access data from SS2000 TDL Sensor
instReading = ss2000serialRead('192.168.1.121', 4001, 57)
print instReading
SS2000TabPopulate = BenchDB.cursor()
SS2000TabPopulate.execute("insert into ss2000 values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                        instReading)
```

====
Red

Comment: That's not how LCs... or lists... or Python works.

Comment: What is `instReading`? You're iterating over it, but you're also calling it as a function. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instReading` is *already* a sequence.

```
....execute(..., instReading)
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, I just tried that myself, and sure enough.... I think I was thinking too much.... Gotta be careful or I'll hurt myself!  :o)